# Как правильно использовать селекторы?

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#company">О компании</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#services">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Сотрудники</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacts">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**CSS:**
**1 вариант**

```
.main-menu a:hover{
    background-color: #F5F5F5 ;
}
```

===============================

**2 вариант**

```
a:hover{
    background-color: #F5F5F5 ;
}
```

Почему при 1 варианте CSS все работает, а при 2 не работает

Comment: У меня в обоих случаях CSS работает нормально, может у Вас там классы перекрываются?

Comment: И второй работает http://jsfiddle.net/5jmjwz3e/ :)

Comment: так то работают оба. может у Вас уже после имеются стили, которые "переписывают" a:hover

Answer (score 7):

> Чтобы вычислить уровень приоритета (специфичности) какого-либо селектора браузеры используют определенный алгоритм, где каждому типу начисляется определенное количество баллов, определяющее вес селектора. Стили того селектора, который наберет больший вес, в конечном итоге и будут применены к элементу. Если же получится так, что какие-то селекторы, которые воздействуют на один и тот же HTML-элемент наберут одинаковое число баллов, то будут использованы стилевые свойства того, который находится в коде ниже.

1. Универсальный селектор — количество начисляемых баллов равно нулю (0).
2. Селекторы тегов и псевдоэлементы — по одному (1) баллу за каждый.
3. Селекторы атрибутов, классы и псевдоклассы — по десять (10) баллов за каждый.
4. Идентификаторы — по сто (100) баллов за каждый идентификатор находящийся в селекторе.
5. Атрибут style — встроенные стили не используют селекторов, а указываются непосредственно внутри тегов элементов, но при этом они имеют самый высокий приоритет исчисляемый тысячей (1000) баллов.

Пример

```
* { } /* 0 баллов */
em { } /* 1 балл */
p::first-letter { } /* 2 балла (один селектор тегов и один псевдоэлемент) */
p [title="Приветствие"] { } /* 11 баллов (по одному селектору тегов и атрибутов) */
div.fine .one { } /* 21 балл (два класса и один селектор тегов) */
#header a:hover { } /* 111 баллов (идентификатор, селектор тегов и псевдокласс) */
```

Источник http://seodon.ru/css/prioritety-stilej.php P.S. Хотя, где-то я это видел в другом месте О_о

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта работают, если создать пустые файлы и вставить ваш код.
Значит, где-то мешают другие стили.

Answer (score 0):

Работать будет и первом и во втором варианте, скорее всего у вас просто закешировались. Для того чтоюы сбросить кеш, нажмите F12 (откройте dev) консоль в хроме и прааой кнопкой мыши нажмите на кнопку обновления страницы -> аппаратная перезагрузка и очстка кеша

Answer (score 0):

Конечно первый. Второй поменяет все ссылки на сайте, что скорее всего не является желаемым поведением. А вот все ссылки в блоке навигации - выглядит логично.